# How to find an index of a string within a List in .Net 2.0

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the index number of a string within a List. I tried the following code:

```
List<string> Markets = new List<string>() {"HKG", "TYO", "NSE", "STU", "FRA", "LON", "SIN", "MIL", "TSE", "ASX", "STO", "AEX", "MEX", "NSE", "EPA", "SWX", "CVE", "BRU", "SWX"};
int index = Markets.FindIndex("HKG");
```

The following errors came up:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.FindIndex(System.Predicate<string>)' has some invalid arguments
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Predicate<string>'

Any idea how to get the compiler to like this code?

P.S. I am using QuantShare's C# which is supposed to be .Net 2.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int index = Markets.IndexOf("HKG");
```

Answer (score 9):

Since it's a predicate, you should plug in a lambda function.

`FindIndex(x => x == "HKG")`

See: http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda

Answer (score 1):

use FindIndex:

```cs
    List<string> Markets = new List<string>() { "HKG", "TYO", "NSE", "STU", "FRA", "LON", "SIN", "MIL", "TSE", "ASX", "STO", "AEX", "MEX", "NSE", "EPA", "SWX", "CVE", "BRU", "SWX" };
    var index = Markets.FindIndex(a => a == "HKG");
```